# Python SQLite error binding, unsupported type with string

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Running my Python **3.4** program with a SQLite3 database (using SQLAlchemy), I get a Interface Error : *Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.* I already read lots of stuff about it (including here) but can't find the issue.

Software versions :

- sqlite3 : 3.8.7.1
- python : 3.4.2
- sqlalchemy : 1.0.5 (python 3 version, installed with python3 pip)

Db création :

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///file.db')
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
certs = sqlalchemy.Table('certs',metadata,
        sqlalchemy.Column('id',sqlalchemy.Integer,primary_key=True),
        sqlalchemy.Column('owner',sqlalchemy.String,nullable=False),
        sqlalchemy.Column('device',sqlalchemy.String,nullable=False),
        sqlalchemy.Column('commonName',sqlalchemy.String,nullable=False,unique=True),
        sqlalchemy.Column('revoked',sqlalchemy.Boolean,nullable=False,default=False),)
metadata.create_all(engine)
conn = engine.connect()
```

SQLite result :

```
sqlite> .schema certs
CREATE TABLE certs (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        owner VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        device VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        "commonName" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        revoked BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        UNIQUE ("commonName"),
        CHECK (revoked IN (0, 1))
);
```

The lines failing :

```
print(">> "+login+" "+str(type(login)))
s = sqlalchemy.select([certs]).where(sqlalchemy.and_(certs.c.owner == login,certs.c.revoked == False))
result = conn.execute(s)
```

The output :

```
>> jmartin2 <class 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1139, in _execute_context 
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 450, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

The SQL query generated :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type. 
[SQL: 'Select certs.id, certs.owner, certs.device, certs."commonName", certs.revoked 
    FROM certs 
    WHERE certs.owner = ?
    AND certs.revoked = 0'] 
[parameters: ('jmartin',)]
```

So what I understand from that is there is a type error in the first param, which is the owner = login here. Owner column is a Varchar, and as the print shows login is a str.

So I have no idea what's going on here ! Anyone has an idea by any luck ?

Thanks !

## More info :

So, the function is called a first time with several values returned wu the select, it works so it switches all entries to `revoked=1`. A little after, I call it a second time. There is no `revoked=0`entries left, which means select should return an empty set of results. This is expected behavior. Else, I have this exception raised.

Here is the full function :

```
def revokeUserCerts(login):
    s = sqlalchemy.select([users]).where(users.c.login == login)
    result = conn.execute(s)
    userData = result.fetchone()
    if userData == None:
        msg.warn("Impossible de trouver l'utilisateur "+login)
        return 1

    ###############   This is the one that fails :
    s = sqlalchemy.select([certs]).where(sqlalchemy.and_(certs.c.owner==login,certs.c.revoked==False))
    result = conn.execute(s)
    for row in result:
        if revokeCert(login,row['device']) != 0:
            msg.fail("Erreur de révocation du certificat du device "+row['device'])
            return 1
    msg.info("Tous les certificats de l'utilisateur "+login+" ont été révoqués")
    return 0
```

Called with `revokeUserCerts("jmartin2")`, first time works well, sqlite CLI confirms everything is revoked, second time fails miserably raising this "sqlite3.InterfaceError"...

Answer (score 1):

The `owner` column has the `VARCHAR` type, so SQLAlchemy is expecting a string. Your value, however, is not a real string.

```
>>> print type(login)
<class 'str'>
>>> print type('foo')
<type 'str'>
```

This is probably a class that simulates a string, so casting it into a real string should work. Then,

```
s = sqlalchemy.select([certs]).where(sqlalchemy.and_(certs.c.owner == str(login), certs.c.revoked == False))
```

Should work as well.

Comment: I can't cast from class str to type str, and type('foo') gives me class str.
I forgot to add, this is python 3.4

Comment: After some research it looks like str type has disappeared from python3.4, replaced by str class.

Comment: In that case, I don't know. I can't seem to reproduce your error: it works for me with both Python 3.4 and Python 2.7.

Comment: Actually, here are a couple of other things you might check: what version of SQLite3 and SQLAlchemy are you using? how do you create the ``conn`` object (I did ``engine.connect()``)? Also, SQLite3 has the notion of "type affinity", so values that are not strictly strings can be stored as ``VARCHAR``: since you're doing a ``SELECT``, maybe your database contains something that SQLAlchemy can't handle?

Comment: I added versions & engine creation in the question.   
I read about type affinity, but all data in the database is added from strings from the same script, so "logically" it should not raise any issue...

Comment: I tried the same thing on Ubuntu14.04 with Python3.4.2+SQLite3.8.2 and on Ubuntu15.04 with Python3.4.3+3.8.7.4, both with SQLAlchemy1.0.5, and both worked. It's possible there's a bug specifically in your versions, but it's unlikely.
But do try to isolate the error even further: does removing the ``and_`` and the ``certs.c.revoked == False`` work? Does creating an SQLite cursor and executing the exact same query manually work?

Comment: Where does the login value comes from ? It's not a builting python type (a normal string would be displayed as builtins.str in python 3, not class str). So my guess is that it's a value comming from some GUI widget such as a qt string or somthing like that. You may want to try to to cast it in some way such as sqlalchemy.and_(certs.c.owner == str(login),certs.c.revoked == False)

Comment: That's also what I thought, but @Nico Cnd is right: in Python 3, ``type('')`` (and even just ``str``) prints out as ``<class 'str'>``.

Comment: The string comes from the database itself. I also tried as a regular string var, same result. This is nonsense...